# Ant Design - How to remove arrow icon in Select component?

Tags: select, css-selectors, antd, ant-design-pro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gisgK.png)
I'm using Select in Ant Design and don't know how to remove this icon.
Does anyone know the solution?

I try to edit some css and try config provider also but nothing work. Maybe i don't know the right way to do it
Hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `null` to `suffix` prop in Select Component.

```
import { Select } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Select
            style={{ width: '200px' }}
            suffixIcon={null}
            options={[
                { value: '1', label: '1' },
                { value: '2', label: '2' }
            ]}
        />
    );
};

export default App;
```

[image]